# HighMaps: Align ColorAxis within Legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

http://jsfiddle.net/sgrg93/brev29jg/

```
legend:{
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 300     //to increase the width of legend more than that of ColorAxis
},
```

In the above fiddle, width of the legend is more than that of the ColorAxis. The ColorAxis is left aligned within the legend. Is there any way to align the ColorAxis to the center or the right within the legend box?

I don't want to use

```
this.legend.contentGroup.translate(50,0)
```

on load() event of chart

Comment: Let me know what is wrong with the using translate() method?

Comment: @SebastianBochan there is nothing wrong with using it. I just wanted to know if it can be done using some attribute in legend, colorAxis, etc. in the options json passed to Highcharts

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can alter the object 'legend' to disable it with:

```
legend:{
  enabled: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need the whitespace at all?

If you remove the width property, you could simply make the surrounding box the correct size for your legend, as so:

```
 legend:{
           borderWidth:1
           //width:300
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brev29jg/1/